Why is a dynamic picklist query in my Custom LWC component executing twice when added to App Builder and click save?
I have a Custom LWC component exposed on a Record Detail page in Salesforce. This component includes a Design attribute that dynamically queries picklist values. When I drag and drop this component onto an App Builder page and click save.After clicking save, a user log is generated showing that the dynamic picklist query is executed twice.I placed 50 LWC components on a builder page, and each component executes a query twice. When I click save, I get a 'Too many SOQL queries: 101' error. I'm uncertain about the reason behind this double execution of the query when click save. Can anyone help with this issue?



JS code:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ListView extends LightningElement {

    @api AccountName;
   
}

HTML code:
<template>
    test
</template>

XML code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <masterLabel>List View</masterLabel>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage,lightning__AppPage,lightning__UtilityBar">
            <property 
                name="AccountName" 
                default="" 
                required="true" 
                type="String" 
                datasource="apex://AccountNamePicklist" 
                description="Name of the List view configuration. This value is required." 
                label="Configuration Name"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Apex code:
    public with sharing class AccountNamePicklist extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {
    List<Account> AccountList = new List<Account>();
    public AccountNamePicklist() {        
        System.debug('enter Method');
        /*---------------------- This query executed Two times ---------------------*/
        AccountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 2000];
    }
     
    public override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue() {
        VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('', '');
        if (AccountList.size() > 0) {
            defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow(AccountList[0].Name, AccountList[0].Name); 
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
    
    public override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows AccountNameList = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        for (Account acc : AccountList) {
            VisualEditor.DataRow value = new VisualEditor.DataRow(acc.Name, acc.Name);  
            AccountNameList.addRow(value);  
        }
        return AccountNameList;
    }
}
}


While not an answer to your exact question, if you're hitting the 101 SOQL limit error it must all be executing in a single transaction, meaning you could store the result of the SOQL query in a static variable, resulting in the query only happening once.

This doesn't answer your question of why it's happening twice, but I'm assuming the reason you're asking is because you're hitting limits and that's what you want to find a solution for.
If you're hitting the 101 SOQL limit, the system must be calling your class multiple times in a single transaction.
As such, you can probably put your AccountList in a static getter which will probably solve your 101 SOQL query limit.  (If not, leave this answer here and let us know so anyone else looking at this question learns if this doesn't work)
ie.
public with sharing class AccountNamePicklist extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {

    private static List<Account> AccountList { get {
        if(AccountList == null) {
            AccountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 2000];
        }
        return AccountList;
    } set; }
    
    public AccountNamePicklist() {
    }
     
    public override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue() {
        VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('', '');
        if (AccountList.size() > 0) {
            defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow(AccountList[0].Name, AccountList[0].Name); 
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
    
    public override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows AccountNameList = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        for (Account acc : AccountList) {
            VisualEditor.DataRow value = new VisualEditor.DataRow(acc.Name, acc.Name);  
            AccountNameList.addRow(value);  
        }
        return AccountNameList;
    }
}


As per this blog,

To prevent the dynamic picklist query from executing twice in the App
Builder, developers can use the NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl method
to generate a URL for the Record Detail page and then use the
window.location.replace method to navigate to the page. This will
ensure that the query is executed only once, after the page is saved.

Example:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin, CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/PicklistController.getPicklistValues';

export default class CustomPicklistComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
 @api fieldName;
 picklistValues;
 @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

 connectedCallback() {
 const pageUrl = this.generateRecordDetailUrl();
 window.location.replace(pageUrl);
 }

 generateRecordDetailUrl() {
 const { state } = this.pageRef;
 return `/lightning/r/${state.recordId}/view`;
 }

}


In this example, the generateRecordDetailUrl method is used to
generate a URL for the Record Detail page, and the
window.location.replace method is used to navigate to the page. This
ensures that the query is executed only once, after the page is saved.

You can also implement caching in your Apex class.
Here is an example of Apex Class:
public with sharing class AccountNamePicklist extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {
        private static List<Account> cachedAccountList;

        public AccountNamePicklist() {
                if (cachedAccountList == null) {
                        System.debug('Querying Accounts');
                        cachedAccountList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WITH USER_MODE ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 2000];
                } else {
                        System.debug('Using Cached Accounts');
                }
        }

        public override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue() {
                VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('', '');
                if (cachedAccountList.size() > 0) {
                        defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow(cachedAccountList[0].Name, cachedAccountList[0].Name);
                }
                return defaultValue;
        }

        public override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
                VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows accountNameList = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
                for (Account acc : cachedAccountList) {
                        VisualEditor.DataRow value = new VisualEditor.DataRow(acc.Name, acc.Name);
                        accountNameList.addRow(value);
                }
                return accountNameList;
        }
}

